# How to copy specific files in a list from subfolders to a folder?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory, copy

I have multiple files (all with the same extention) in different subfolders and I want to copy only a subset of them. For example, consider:

```
A/: 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt
B/: 4.txt, 5.txt, 6.txt
C/: 7.txt, 8.txt, 9.txt
```

I want to copy files `1.txt`, `2.txt`, `5.txt`, and `8.txt` to a new folder.

Is there a way to automate this operation knowing that I have more than 500 subfolders each containing a few thousand files and a list (txt file) of the files I want to copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the list contains complete paths, you can move them in a loop:

```
while read file ; do
   mv "$file" dir/
done < list.txt
```

If the list contains only file names, without paths, you can use globstar.

```
# enable double asterisk to recurse directories
shopt -s globstar

while read file ; do
   mv **/"$file" dir/
done < list.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems to be working on a small trial set. I had to modify it a little to go through all the subfolders. I'll update you once i run it on the main set

Answer (score 0):

So I tweaked the central command in order to go through the subfolders

```
while read file ; do
   mv dir1/*/"$file" dir2/
done < list.txt
```

Thanks

Comment: It's a minor tweak that depends on the contents of your input list. Another option is to use globstar to recurse directories. I have edited my answer to demonstrate.